# An engineer, a mechanic and an athlete walk into a bar

Tags: knowledge, geometry, rebus, literature, chemistry

...to exchange puzzles about the **thing** they talked about the other day and have a drink.

The engineer showed these numbers:

```
2, 8, 14, 2, 99
2, 4,  0, 0,  1
```

The mechanic drew this:
[image]

The athlete presented the following sequence:

```
1 1
0 1
1 0
0 0
0 1
0 0
1 0
0 0
0 1
0 0
1 0
0 1
1 1
```

What is the **thing** they talked about?

Hint 1:

> The answer is 3 words. The answer to each person's puzzle is 1 word. The professions of each person relate to the answers of corresponding puzzles.

Comment: Just some quick things I've noticed right off the bat: the rightmost depiction in the mechanic's image depicts the big dipper constellation, and the leftmost looks like a 2D representation of a 4D cube.

Comment: @TylerSelden The other images are probably rot13(cvr (cv) naq na e fdhner, juvpu yrnqf zr gb oryvrir gurer vf fbzr pvepyr fghss tbvat ba). Not sure what exactly to make of it though

Comment: One thing I thought a few weeks ago about the athlete's sequence is the following: rot13(gur snpg vg'f n frevr bs rknpgyl gjb ahzoref znxrf zr guvat bs fbzrbar qbvat n whzcvat rkrepvfr jurer 1 zrnaf sbbg ba gur tebhaq naq 0 nobir (yvxr qhevat n whzc). Svefg ur fgnaq jvgu gjb srrgf ba gur tebhaq gura ba bar srrg, gura whzcf, ynaqf ba gur bgure sbbg, rgp.)

Comment: @Qise - it's not rot13(whzcvat) per se, but you're very close.

Comment: I also noticed that rot13(gur nguyrgr'f unf 26 ahzoref, juvpu znqr zr guvax bs gur nycunorg. V nyfb abgvprq gur [purzvfgel] gnt, ohg V'z abg fher jurer vg pbhyq pbzr vagb cynl. Cebonoyl abg gur e va n obk, fvapr vg'f ybjrepnfr naq gurer vf ab "e" ryrzrag.)

Comment: @BlueHerring - 26 is just coincidence.

Comment: I'm thinking that the r is supposed to be rot13(evtug nybat fvqr gur cvr, fb gung vg fnlf "cvr e-fdhnerq," gur nern bs n pvepyr.)

Comment: @Qise maybe rot13(na nygreangvir pbhyq or gung gurl ner sbbgfgrcf, va juvpu pnfr vg znl unir fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu gur avar fgrcf vg gbbx?)

Comment: Riding off of Qise's comment, looking at the athlete's numbers made me think of rot13(ehaavat/whzcvat uheqyrf. Jvgu gur "fgrcf" nppryrengvat/qrpryrengvat ba gur raqf, naq yrncvat uheqyrf va orgjrra ba gur 0 0 cnvef.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think they were talking about

> Hirohiko Araki's **Steel Ball Run**.

The engineer's word is:

> **Steel**: `2, 8, 14, 2` and `2, 4, 0, 0` correspond to the electron structure of iron and carbon, which, in an alloy with a 99-to-1 ratio forms steel.

The mechanic's word is the one I am least confident in:

> **Ball**: The pictures are, in order, a **4**-dimensional cube, **pi**e, **r-squared**, and the negation of the Big Dipper, which is part of Ursa Major, the Great **Bear**. $4 \pi r^2$ is the surface area of a sphere, or a ball and a mechanic encounters ball bearings often; removing the bear gives **ball**.

The athlete's word is

> **Run**: As in the comments, the numbers correspond to a running pace where 1 signifies a foot on the ground and 0 signifies otherwise.

Combined with the literature tag, I think this is right.

Comment: Providing an answer to a previously unanswered question is *always* acceptable.